# Calculate max value in an atomic FindAndModify operation

Tags: mongodb

I trying to figure out if is it possible in MongoDB to push an element and in the same time (atomic `FindAndModify` operation) update the max value of the elements in the array.

Example:

```
{
  "_id": "...",
  "max_value": 10,
  "values": [2, 10, 6]
}
```

And after I insert 20, the result would be:

```
{
  "_id": "...",
  "max_value": 20,
  "values": [2, 10, 6, 20]
}
```

The value 20 pushed to the values array, and the max_value field re-calculated (to be 20) in the same atomic operation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Upon further reflection, my original answer was correct, but wasteful. Specifically, the first step is not necessary, so here's a revised version:

You can emulate this process in two steps:

1. findAndModify with `_id` and `max_value` `$lte` the value you're currently attempting to insert. Since `_id` is unique, you know that only zero or one documents can match this query -- assuming that a document with that `_id` exists, it is zero in the case where the `max_value` is greater than what you're inserting, and one in the case where it is less than or equal. In the update, `$push` the new value, and `$set` `max_value`.
2. If and only if step #1 failed, findAndModify again with `_id`, and `$push` the new value to the array. Since step #1 failed, we know that the current `max_value` is greater than the new value, so we can ignore it and just `$push` the new value.

Here's sample Python code to implement this:

```
# the_id is the ObjectId of the document we want to modify
# new_value is the new value to append to the list
rslt1 = rslt2 = None

rslt1 = db.collection.find_and_modify(
    {'_id': the_id, 'max_value': {'$lte': new_value}},
    {'$push': {'array': new_value}, '$set': {'max_value': new_value}})

if rslt1 is None:
    rslt2 = db.collection.find_and_modify(
        {'_id': the_id},
        {'$push': {'array': new_value}})

# only one of these will be non-None; this
# picks whichever is non-None and assigns
# it to rslt
rslt = rslt1 or rslt2
```

---

*(This original answer works, but the updated version above is more efficient.)*

You can emulate this process in three steps:

1. findAndModify a document with the given `_id` **and** with `max_value` `$gt` the current value you're attempting to insert. Since `_id` is unique, you know that only zero or one documents can match this query -- assuming that a document with that `_id` exists, it is zero in the case where the `max_value` is less than what you're inserting, and one in the case where it is greater. The update portion for this findAndModify will `$push` the new value to the array.
2. If and only if step #1 failed, findAndModify again with `_id` and `max_value` `$lte` the value you're currently attempting to insert. In the update, `$push` the new value, and `$set` `max_value`.
3. If and only if step #2 failed, findAndModify again with `_id`, and `$push` the new value to the array. This covers the case where between steps #1 and #2, another thread upped the `max_value` to a value greater than the value you're currently inserting.

Here's sample Python code to implement this:

```
# the_id is the ObjectId of the document we want to modify
# new_value is the new value to append to the list
rslt1 = rslt2 = rslt3 = None
rslt1 = db.collection.find_and_modify(
    {'_id': the_id, 'max_value': {'$gt': new_value}},
    {'$push': {'array': new_value}})

if rslt1 is None:
    rslt2 = db.collection.find_and_modify(
        {'_id': the_id, 'max_value': {'$lte': new_value}},
        {'$push': {'array': new_value}, '$set': {'max_value': new_value}})

if rslt1 is None and rslt2 is None:
    rslt3 = db.collection.find_and_modify(
        {'_id': the_id},
        {'$push': {'array': new_value}})

# only one of these will be non-None; this
# picks whichever is non-None and assigns
# it to rslt
rslt = rslt1 or rslt2 or rslt3
```